# Solving $f'(x)=f(x)f'(f(x)),x>0$ for $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following equation is given:

\begin{align}
f'(x)=f(x)f'(f(x)),x>0
\end{align}

Is there an easy way to solve this equation for $f(x)$?

Thank you

Comment: Well, you could guess-and-check. For example, $f(x) = \mbox{const}$ works ...

Comment: I hope there is a more systematic way to solve this equation.

Comment: $f(x)=\log(x)+c$ seems to be the solution. I tested a few functions ($\exp$, $\log$, ...) and saw that $\log$ works. But hopefully there is another clean way to solve the equation.

Comment: Are you sure? If $f(x) = \log(x) + c$ then $f'(x) = 1/x$ so we have $1/x = (\log(x) + c)\frac{1}{\log(x) + c} = 1$ (when $x\neq e^{-x}$) which is not true for all $x>0$.

Comment: I think $f'(f(x))$ is equal to $\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\log(x)+c}$,  then it works.

Comment: This is not the case: as $f'(x)  = 1/x$, we have $f'(f(x)) = 1/f(x) = 1/(\log(x) + c)$.

Comment: You are right:)